# Graphic novel involving xenoforming of Earth by a malicious intelligence

Tags: story-identification, comics, terraforming

I purchased this graphic novel from a local Borders during the company shutdown & liquidation. It was leant out, and never returned. I rather enjoyed it, and would like to see if more content by the writer/illustrator (or both) exists.

Details from my recollection:

- Graphic novel
- Paperback (Fiction trim size)
- Color palette (red/white/black/gray)

Story synopsis:
A non-descript man living on the outskirts of an urban area (farmer?) gets infected by something that was within a meteor that crashed on his property (nanite?). This object gives the man incredible intelligence, ideas about how to spur human progress & industry, and (possibly) god-like physique.

Using the new intelligence, the man ushers in an era of accelerated growth & development in technology; a utopia.

All over the world, the new machines, factories, and processes invented by the man are in operation.

This is all a front, however, for the intelligence: these machines are what is required to xenoform the Earth into a highly dangerous atmosphere required for its native life.

There are humans that exist after the beginning of the xenoforming. I believe they hide underground and must wear full-body suits as any exposure to the atmosphere would render them dead almost immediately. I believe the nanites permeate the atmosphere, looking for any extant earth-life, and exterminating/xenoforming them upon contact.

For some reason, I'm remembering one such person having scars all over their body... Shape of a dragon? I also remember the graphic novel ending with two such characters dying on the surface after they get a tear in their suits.

Comment: I wanted to add the xenoforming tag, but I lack sufficient reputation here to do so. Could someone please add it to the OP by editing?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Tag added as requested.

Comment: @Moriarty Please read the tag description for the "xenomorph" tag you are adding.  The concept of "xenoforming" is adequately described by the existing "terraforming" tag that is already on this question.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry..

Comment: Unfortunately, terraforming should have a fairly narrowly defined scope of transforming an uninhabitable planet into an earth-like, hence its name: Terraforming. Xenoforming is pretty distinct from that, and why I asked for the new tag to be made. Terraforming should yield thoughts like Red/Green/Blue Mars books by Kim Stanley Robinson. Xenoforming might remind one of those same stories, if they had been written by non-human inhabitants of Mars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Singularity 7* (2004) by Ben Templesmith?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_7):

> The comic tells the story of how Earth was forever changed after **alien nanites arrived in a meteor shower. The nanites, able to shift the molecular structure of any material, bond with the mind of Bobby Hennigan who initially uses the nanites power to improve life on Earth by building complex machines and curing disease.** Unfortunately, Bobby goes crazy, becoming a God-like monster called ‘The Singularity’, destroying everything and forcing humanity to live deep beneath the surface of the Earth.
>
> **This new world is post-apocalyptic, filled with monsters, poisonous gases, and the nanites, which are now used to devour human flesh.** The only things able to go to the surface are the "Gosiodo" - part man / part machine creatures connected to the hive mind of the Singularity and sent out to hunt down the remaining humans, and "Specials" - rare humans who, when exposed to the nanites are mysteriously not killed and instead bond with the nanites, giving them access to strange powers and the ability to survive on the surface.

The following page matches your recollection of a black/white/red palette:

[image: black and white panels​. A character dies]

---

Found with the Google query `comic nanites xenomorph earth` which returned the Wikipedia page. Sometimes a spelling mistake helps; the query `comic nanites xenoform earth`, which I would have used if not for years of occupational hazard of knowing about [Xenomorphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)), does not return the comic, save for this very question.

Comment: You found it! I searched endlessly using the keyword xenoform and found nothing! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Saijin_Naib funny how things work sometimes, right :) you're welcome, enjoy the re-read.

Comment: Using the 'wrong' search term got the right result. That is _amazing_. Also amazing: Ben Templesmith

Comment: I just learned that he's in part responsible for Thirty Days of Night, so I'm well down the path of tracking down more of his works. Thanks again, everyone :)